# async/await loop await

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I want to test use loop to `await`.

---

```
// works fine
async function asyncFunc() {
    let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(await arr[i]);
    }
}

asyncFunc()
```

---

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    arr.forEach(function(el) {    // get an error:  SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
        console.log(await el);
    })
}

asyncFunc()
```

---

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    arr.forEach((el) => {        // get an error here:  SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
        console.log(await el);
    })
}

asyncFunc()
```

**Can someone tell me what's wrong here?**

```
editor: VS code
node: 8.0.0
```

I know that i can't use `await` out of the current `async function` context.

So i am sure i will get an error on the second one.

But i do not know why i also get an error on the third one. **Does the arrow function and the async function have the different context ???**

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're getting the error on the line below your comment, right?

Comment: You're trying to use `await` in a function that is not an `async` function (the `forEach()` callback function).

Comment: In what environment are you getting that error message? It's not super helpful - it should rather say that the `await` keyword cannot be used there.

Comment: @Bergi isn't `await` parsed as a plain identifier in contexts where it can't be used? Or maybe I'm thinking of something else.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that's what happens here - it expects either `console.log(await)` or `console.log(await, el)` or something, so that's why it's complaining about a missing parenthesis. Which is what I'd call "not helpful"

Comment: @Bergi I update the question just now, could you take a glance? thank u

Comment: Yes, it does not matter whether it's an arrow function or a function expression or any other function syntax, they're two different functions.

Comment: `async/await` is part of ES2017, not ES2016.